# Refactoring ifs and a foreach

Tags: c#, oop, optimization, refactoring

I have two ifs in a function that sorts users by their roles, the users that access an application. Each user is an object with properties like name, password, which are just simple strings, but each user has an inner object, named Role that has a property Name, which is a string. The code looks something like:

```
    public GetUsersSorted(string sortBy)
       {
             if(sortBy=='roles')
             {
                 usersCollection = get the users, but not sorted by anything
             }
             else
             {  
                 usersCollection = get users sorted sorted by something else
             }
        
             items = mapUsersToDTO(usersCollection)
        
             if(sortBy=='roles')
             {
                 items = sortUsersInMemory(items)
             }
       }

private mapUsersToDTO(List usersSorted)
{
    foreach(var item in usersSorted)
    {
      item.Roles = item.Roles.OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList(); //here I sort the roles inside the user
    }

    usersSorted = usersSorted.OrderBy(b => b.Roles.First().Name()).ToList();

    return usersSorted;
}
```

How can I sort them more efficiently, based on the Name of their Role? This works too but, I sort them based only on the first role, and I want to sort them based on all the names of their roles

Comment: What do you mean by "sort them based on all the names of their roles"? Which of ("A", "Y") ("X", "B") should sort before the other?

Comment: (A, Y), (B, X) - the result

Comment: Why? What is the exact rule?

Comment: I want to sort the roles in alphabetical order for each user, then order the users depending on the name of their front-most alphabetical role. If we have for example roles like (z,v,a), (a,b,c) , (c,k,g), (s, t, b) then we should sort them like this: (a,b,c) , (a,v,z) , (b,s,t) , (c,g,k)

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to add this requirement? It is easily overlooked if its only in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a list in your list and you want the nested list also ordered.

```
users.Select(x=>x.Roles.OrderBy(y=>y.Name).ToList())
     .OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

This orders the internal list, then orders the outer list.

If you posted some actual code or maybe the model for your data, I could tailor that solution better.